# Should I use Unity Canvas for non-UI game objects?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I'm trying to do simple card game. I want players to drag and drop cards from hand to table, from deck etc. The simplest and cleanest solution for drag and drop I found is to use Image object on canvas with own script. I also found some tutorials for how to handle dragging and dropping on sprites and now I'm confused. I'm pretty new to Unity and I thought that canvas and its objects should be used for UI not for game itself. So here is my question. Should I be using canvas for handling non-UI game objects and my initial thought that Canvas is for UI only is just convention or is there some penalty for using UI objects for "*normal*" game objects?

Comment: We have [some](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/119323/39518) [previous](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139803/39518) [questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/192383/39518) asking whether to use canvases for card games, so I do recommend searching before posting new ones. The general theme is: if a game engine lets you do something, and you find that thing useful, and it's not killing your performance profiling, *it's probably fine*. In gamedev, there's usually no one canonical "way it *should/must* be done", so go with what works for you, and post here for help when it doesn't.

Comment: Myself, I've used canvasses for each card / card stack in a card game and observed no deal-breaking issues. If your mileage varies, try editing your question to describe the specific problem you've encountered making canvases work for your needs, then we can re-open your question and suggest potential fixes for that problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried searching for similar question but failed. I wasn't sure what should I look for to be honest. Nonetheless, thanks for links to question and your response.

Comment: All three of those links were ones I found in the [two pages of search results for "card canvas"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=card%20canvas), so even a pretty simplistic search can get good hits. 

Comment: I definitely need to improve my search skills then ;)